# Convert map coordinates to screen

Tags: java, gis, shapefile

I am trying to convert world coordinates to pixel coordinates. The problem is, some files (shapefiles) do not convert as it should. The lines are slanted or moved, they should look exactly as when I load the file for display.

The reason I am converting the lines is because it needs to display in Adobe Illustrator, and normal map coordinates are much to large to display properly.

Is there a better way to convert world coordinates to screen coordinates more reliably?
(the convertLines method is where all the conversion is happening)

```
    ArrayList<FeatureLine> temp = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        MCV_TestProgram test = new MCV_TestProgram();
    }

    public MCV_TestProgram() {
        temp.add(new FeatureLine("2466308.97 709571.48, 2466306.03 709566.79", 0));
        temp.add(new FeatureLine("2466800.14 710357.15, 2466308.97 709571.48", 1));
        temp.add(new FeatureLine("2456506.25 707356.2, 2456487.75 707715.23, 2456450.68 707809.01", 2));
        temp.add(new FeatureLine("2324352.2 669626.61, 2324365.6 669328.81, 2324146.77 669316.22, 2324165.41 669264.1, 2324174.26 669057.93, 2324192.39 668895.68, 2324211.04 668561.95, 2324219.11 668494.04, 2324230.7 668370.9, 2324247.66 668128.16, 2324260.89 667951.94, 2324268.86 667848.91, 2324278.83 667705.33, 2324289.97 667508.67", 3));

        convertLines(temp);
    }

    // Converts map lines to fit in smaller window (mainly for Adobe Illustrator)
    private ArrayList<FeatureLine> convertLines(ArrayList<FeatureLine> lines) {
        ArrayList<FeatureLine> convertedCoords = new ArrayList();

        try {
            Rectangle imageBounds = new Rectangle(250, 200, 1000, 800);
            CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = createCRS();
            ReferencedEnvelope mapBounds = new ReferencedEnvelope(2104208.77, 2595754.33, 500627.08, 1286916.23, crs);
            AffineTransform world2screen = createTransform(mapBounds, imageBounds);

            for (FeatureLine coord : lines) {
                Point2D screenCoordStart = world2screen.transform(coord.StartPoint, null);
                Point2D screenCoordEnd = world2screen.transform(coord.EndPoint, null);

                if (coord.StartPoint.x != 0.0) {
                    convertedCoords.add(new FeatureLine(screenCoordStart, screenCoordEnd));
                }
            }
        } catch (FactoryException | MismatchedDimensionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MCV_TestProgram.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error occured while converting lines", ex);
        }

        return convertedCoords;
    }

    // Custom line class to store line data, StartPoint and Endpoint (coordinates)
    // of one unbreaking line.
    public class FeatureLine {

        private Point2D.Double StartPoint = new Point2D.Double();
        private Point2D.Double EndPoint = new Point2D.Double();

        public FeatureLine(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
            StartPoint.x = x1;
            StartPoint.y = y1;
            EndPoint.x = x2;
            EndPoint.y = y2;
        }

        public FeatureLine(Point2D.Double start, Point2D.Double end) {
            StartPoint = start;
            EndPoint = end;
        }

        public FeatureLine(Point2D start, Point2D end) {
            StartPoint = (Point2D.Double) start;
            EndPoint = (Point2D.Double) end;
        }

        public FeatureLine(String parseString, int index) {

            String latlon[];
            String xy1[];
            String xy2[];

            double x1, y1;
            double x2, y2;

            try {
                if (!parseString.equals("")) {
                    latlon = parseString.split(",");

                    xy1 = latlon[0].split(" ");
                    xy2 = latlon[1].replaceFirst(" ", "").split(" ");

                    x1 = Double.parseDouble(xy1[0]);
                    y1 = Double.parseDouble(xy1[1]);

                    x2 = Double.parseDouble(xy2[0]);
                    y2 = Double.parseDouble(xy2[1]);

                    StartPoint.x = x1;
                    StartPoint.y = y1;

                    EndPoint.x = x2;
                    EndPoint.y = y2;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error occured while creating line at: " + index + " ", ex);
            }
        }

        public double getX(int index) {
            if (index == 0) {
                return StartPoint.x;
            } else {
                return EndPoint.x;
            }
        }

        public double getY(int index) {
            if (index == 0) {
                return StartPoint.y;
            } else {
                return EndPoint.y;
            }
        }

        public void setX(double x, int index) {
            if (index == 0) {
                StartPoint.x = x;
            } else {
                EndPoint.x = x;
            }
        }

        public void setY(double y, int index) {
            if (index == 0) {
                StartPoint.y = y;
            } else {
                EndPoint.y = y;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            return (builder.append(String.valueOf(StartPoint.x)).append(" ").append(String.valueOf(StartPoint.y)).append(", ")
                    .append(String.valueOf(EndPoint.x)).append(" ").append(String.valueOf(EndPoint.y))).toString();
        }
    }

    /**
    * Uses the window's aspect ratio to choose a scale factor for the map,
    * and constructs an AffineTransform to scale the shapefile's contents.
    */
    private AffineTransform createTransform(ReferencedEnvelope mapEnvelope, Rectangle imageBounds) {
        double mapWidth = mapEnvelope.getWidth();
        double mapHeight = mapEnvelope.getHeight();
        double imageWidth = imageBounds.getWidth();
        double imageHeight = imageBounds.getHeight();
        double sx = imageWidth / mapWidth;
        double sy = imageHeight / mapHeight;
        double aspectRatio = mapWidth / mapHeight;
        double scale = aspectRatio < 1 ? sy : sx;
        AffineTransform m = new AffineTransform();
        m.scale(scale, scale);
        return m;
    }

    // Create CRS from custom data
    private CoordinateReferenceSystem createCRS() throws FactoryException {

        String wkt = "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_Michigan_GeoRef_Feet_US\"," +
            "GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\"," +
            "DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\"," +
            "SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\", 6378137.0, 298.257222101]]," +
            "PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\", 0.0]," +
            "UNIT[\"degree\", 0.017453292519943295]," +
            "AXIS[\"Longitude\", EAST]," +
            "AXIS[\"Latitude\", NORTH]]," +
            "PROJECTION[\"Hotine_Oblique_Mercator\"]," +
            "PARAMETER[\"longitude_of_center\", -86.0]," +
            "PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_center\", 45.30916666666666]," +
            "PARAMETER[\"azimuth\", 337.25555555555593]," +
            "PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\", 0.9996]," +
            "PARAMETER[\"false_easting\", 8355401.583000001]," +
            "PARAMETER[\"false_northing\", -14284780.538]," +
            "PARAMETER[\"rectified_grid_angle\", 337.25555555555593]," +
            "UNIT[\"foot_survey_us\", 0.3048006096012192]," +
            "AXIS[\"X\", EAST]," +
            "AXIS[\"Y\", NORTH]]";

        CRSFactory crsFactory = ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSFactory(null);
        CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = crsFactory.createFromWKT(wkt);

        return crs;
    }
```